# How to find the byte offset in STDIN in Python?

Tags: python, file, stdin

Normally, I would do something like:

```
f=open(path)

for line in iter(f.readline, ''):

    print f.tell()
```

However, seek operations are not possible with:

```
import sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):

    print sys.stdin.tell()
```

Comment: why do you need this? stdin is not a file, it's file like object.

Comment: I want to pipe streaming input and record the positions of certain parts of the input, such as to mark the end or beginning of lines in the stream.

Comment: I think stringIO module is what I need.

Comment: A pipe is not seekable, in any language.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate file offset yourself.

```
import sys

offset = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
  print offset
  offset += len(line)
```